# Adding additional fields to the login feature in asp.net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I have a application that i am creating in ASP.net i need to be able to update a new column in the table users which is set up automatic with a asp.net project. I am trying to add a address line to the code

This is code that i have so far

```
     TextBox address1TextBox =
      (TextBox)RegisterUserWizardStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("Address1TextBox");
    TextBox userNameTextBox =
(TextBox)RegisterUserWizardStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("UserName");

    Profile.



    Membership.UpdateUser(user);
```

Any one have any ideas of how i would even update this column in the user table that i have.

Any ideas of how i could update the address line1 table in the database that comes with a visual studio 2010 project.

Comment: If you're not using the standard fields, you'd have to call your own stored procedure to update the custom fields.

Comment: Your code sample got cut off.

Comment: Web site or Web Application Project template? Profiles only available out of the box for the former.

Comment: Website sorry not web application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to store in the profile the additional fields you need or store these additional fields in a database table, and link the two tables together, the asp.net user table and your table or profile.  There is an extra key field in the membership table called MembershipObjectKey or something like that, that is a generic field that allows you to store the key of the record in your user table, so you can use that to link the two.

HTH.

Comment: How do i add the additional fields into the profile and if i do this will it save into the database.

Comment: The profile configuration file as in this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2y3fs9xs.aspx.  It does store the values to an aspnet table.

Comment: I have added a new coloum to the table containing a address1 feild any ideas how i could update this with data from a text box

Comment: You added address1 to what table?  aspnet_membership table?  your user table?

Comment: Convert the control to a templated control, and add your additional fields that you require.